# CSS Menu Dropdown Hover issue

Tags: html, css, navigation

I'm having an issue with a responsive dropdown navigation list whereby if you move the mouse slowly off of a parent link, the submenu for the last parent item shows instead.

I've uploaded an example at: http://webe.emv3.com/aps/twelve/primary.html

If you hover over 'Top Up Card' then move the mouse slowly downwards towards the submenu, help is activated instead.

Do you have any idea why this might be happening?

Comment: what browser are you using? I am not able to replicate this problem using chrome.

Comment: I replicated this problem with chrome version 28.0.1500.72

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've located the reason. There was an issue with the borders on line 153-156:

```
.rdd-menu .submenu-panel    {
    border-radius:0 0 10px 10px;
    border:1px solid #ccc;
    border-top:0;
```

Even though the top border had been removed, having the left, right, and bottom borders caused the issue. Removing them has resolved it.

I appreciate your help with this. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

It's because `.rdd-menu .submenu-panel` is not hidden and/or positioned out of the way. So when you :hover over the parent all the `.submenu-panel`'s are still visible. Having a `height:0` does not hide an element.

A simple:

```
.rdd-menu .submenu-panel {
   display: none;
}    

.rdd-menu li:hover > .submenu-panel {
   display: block;
}
```

will fix it. You can disregard your height declarations too.

**edit:** I just noticed you had transitions on them. You can just position the submenu's offscreen to keep the transitions intact:

```
.rdd-menu .submenu-panel {
   top: -10%;
}    

.rdd-menu li:hover > .submenu-panel {
   top: 100%;
}
```

Comment: Hi Barrett, Thank you. This has resolved the issue with the last parent element appearing, but created a new issue with the height of both the submenu panel (the blurb beneath the default image on the left hand side when the parent element is hovered) and also the related info (the blurb in the same location appearing when the individual list items are hovered). There was some jQuery missing from the original page which used a plugin to set the heights of both the submenu panel and related items to be uniform, which has now been included.

Comment: I've created a video to show what it looked like previously, with the equal heights on the panels if it helps? http://webe.emv3.com/aps/twelve/dropdown.mp4